# Replace a multibyte character with single byte codepoint (e.g. a space) in the middle of a large UTF8 file

Tags: replace, utf-8

I have large text files in UTF8 that contain a mix of ASCII symbols (so UTF8 will use 1 byte to encode) and higher code points that require up to four bytes (AFAIU).
I would like to "blank out" some portions of the file, i.e. overwrite portions of text with spaces (U+0020).

I can surely rewrite the whole file, but they can be gigabytes in size. I only need to overwrite a few characters in the middle, so this look to be a big waste.

The problem is how to deal with multibyte characters without breaking the encoding scheme. E.g. character **μ** (U+03BC, binary: ‭0011 1011 1100‬), it does require two bytes. I can't just replace the first byte with U+020 and leave the second byte dangling as-is in the file, right?
Does UTF8 have some notion of a "blank"/"skip"/"unused" byte?

I guess replacing multibyte characters with the corresponding number of spaces will work, but I'd prefer to replace them with a single one if possible.